# How to use esc_attr here?

Tags: php

I don't know if it's ok how to use `esc_attr` in

```
echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' );
```

I got this. is it ok or is there an error?

```
echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title'););
```

Comment: Extra semicolon. use error reporting

Answer (score 1):

If by esc_attr you mean the integrated wordpress function, you should put a string between the parenthesis. And it's used to escape html attributes.

In your case, you should get rid of the first semicolon:

```
echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('title'));
```